# Javascript Request to iOS Swift Request

Tags: javascript, ios, json, swift, request

I have a working Javascript Ajax request:

```
$.ajax({
                        type: "Put",
                        url: encodeURI("localhost.."),
                        contentType: "application/json",


                        data: JSON.stringify({changes:[{upd:'summary', val:'Test'}]}),

                        success: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        },
                        error: function(response) {
                            console.log(response);
                        }
                    });
```

Now i want to translate this to Swift.

I tried:

```
// create the request & response
    let request = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: NSURL(string: "localhost..")!, cachePolicy: NSURLRequestCachePolicy.ReloadIgnoringLocalCacheData, timeoutInterval: 5)


    // create some JSON data and configure the request
    let jsonString = "{\"changes\":[{\"upd\":\"summary\",\"val\":test}]}"


    request.HTTPBody = jsonString.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding, allowLossyConversion: true)
    request.HTTPMethod = "PUT"
    request.setValue("application/json", forHTTPHeaderField: "Content-Type")

    let session = NSURLSession.sharedSession()

    let task = session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: {data, response, error -> Void in

        let err1: NSError? = nil
        do
        {
            let json = try NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!, options: NSJSONReadingOptions.MutableContainers)
            print(json)
        }
        catch
        {
            print(err1)
        }
    })

    task.resume()
```

I think there is an issue with the JSON string, the error that i get :-

> nsdebugdescription: json text did not start with array or object

Comment: I think `allowLossyConversion` should definitely be `false`.

Comment: Also, `test` in your JSON string should be enclosed in commas: `{\"changes\":[{\"upd\":\"summary\",\"val\":\"test\"}]}`

Comment: ok tried this, but still get the same error

Comment: ahh now it works thx @paulvs

Comment: Cool, added as an answer in case my comments were the correct solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think `allowLossyConversion` should definitely be false.

Also, `test` in your JSON string should be enclosed in quotes: `{\"changes\":[{\"upd\":\"summary\",\"val\":\"test\"}]}`.

Comment: I think you mean "quotes" not "commas". :-)